# How to Allow a "?" Character in a Route Parameter in symfony3

Tags: routes, symfony

i user symfony3 in my project and use a routing in project similar bellow

```
user_anoref:
path:     /noref/{url}
defaults: { _controller: UserBundle:Default:noref }
requirements:
    url: ".+"
methods: [GET]
```

but when use in url ? character routing is error .

i used this url in routing

```
http://qnf.ir/noref/?http://eshoptech.ir
```

please help me

Comment: Please, adds the error message and explain how you use `?` character, when generate the url? or into path definition?

Comment: error when use ? in url 
No route found for "GET /noref/"

Comment: Well, how do you generate that url ? by using javascript ? or using twig `path()` function ??

Comment: this url is generated manual and used this script
{ public function norefAction($url)
    {
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url='.$url.'"><meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer"><a id="sendurl" rel="noreferrer" href="'.$url.'" ></a><form id="submitform" action="'.$url.'" ></form><script>document.getElementById(\'sendurl\').click();</script><script>document.getElementById(\'submitform\').submit();</script>';
        die();
    }{

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your regex to match http url strings, this is untested!

```
user_anoref:
    path:     /noref/{url}
    defaults: { _controller: UserBundle:Default:noref }
    requirements:
        url: "(http[s]?:\/\/)?([^\/\s]+\/)(.*)"
    methods: [GET]
```