# Symfony routing annotation

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to add a new route on a controller, and I ran into a problem when using an email parameter:

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

   /**
     * @Route("/foo/{email}", methods="GET")
     *
     * @param string $email
     *
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function fooAction(string $email) { 
        return JsonResponse::create('OK!');
    }
```

It seems that Symfony routing doesn't allow `.`.

- 127.0.0.1 [200]: /foo/test@testcom
- 127.0.0.1 [404]: /foo/test@test.com

Do I need to add something to make it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok it's because I'm in a dev env, and I start the server using

> php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public

using symfony/web-server-bundle it works

Comment: So set the question as resolved by specifying this answer is the solution

Answer (score 0):

Try to end the route with '/'

@Route("/foo/{email}/", methods="GET")

Answer (score 0):

You need to URL encode the email-address first?

Answer (score 0):

You should solve that with a regex, trys something [like this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39640300/8801301)

Hope it helps!